# Is $AC(I)$ a separable space?

Tags: real-analysis

Let assume $I\subset \mathbb{R}$ and we denote $AC(I)$ by the absolutely continuous function on $I$. Then, in $L^\infty$ norm, do we have $AC(I)$ is separable?

My answer is not, as $C^0$ is not separable... But I feel uncomfortable with my answer... Could somebody give me a more clear answer? Thx!

update: Sorry $C^0$ is separable... So I would assume that $AC(I)$ is separable for $I$ is bounded. How about $I=\mathbb{R}$?

It looks to me that $AC(I)$ is not a Banach space even with $L^\infty$ norm... I'm sorry if this question does not make sense...

Comment: What do you impose on $I$? The space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with $\sup$ norm is separable...

Comment: Polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{Q}$ are dense and countable in $C([a,b])$. For your question, it really depends on what is $I$ and the topology of $I$.

Comment: So I would think $AC(I)$ is separable if $I$ is bounded? what about $I=R$? I can not think another norm on continuous function other then $L^\infty$... but looks like $AC(I)$ is not a Banach space anyway...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separability is a property of topological spaces, so your question makes sense.

Neglecting the Banach property issue (the limit of AC functions with respect to $L^\infty$ norm is not AC in general), if $I=\mathbb{R}$ then seems not separable: consider the family $\{\exp(ax):a>0\}$, the $L^\infty$ distance between $\exp(ax)$ and $\exp(bx)$ is infinite whenever $a\neq b$. For any $a$, let $A_a$ be an open ball of radius 1 containing $\exp(ax)$, and all such balls are disjoint...

Even if $I$ were bounded we could find an uncountable family $(f_j)$ such that the distance ($L^\infty$) between $f_j$ and $f_h$ is infinite (e.g. $I:=(0,1)$, $f_j:=x^{-j}$, $j>0$)

Comment: So you are saying even for $I$ bounded $AC$ is not separable? I thought it is because polynomials is dense in $C^0$ and hence in $AC$.

Comment: No, polynomials are not dense $C^0(X)$ in general, they are dense if $X$ is compact.

Comment: Oh i c. If $I=[0,1]$ then $AC$ is separable, but if $I=(0,1)$ then $AC$ may not separable right?

Comment: Exactly, consider the family $(f_j)_{j>0}$ from my answer, and let $U_j$ be a ball of radius 1 containing $f_j$. Then $U_j\cap U_i=\emptyset$ whenever $i\neq j$, thus you have uncountably many disjoint open sets (hence not separable)

Comment: I think the counter example is in $C((0,1))$, not $AC((0,1))$. Since $AC\subset BV$ the functions in $AC$ must be bounded.

Comment: Oh right, I did not notice this... Then seems $AC((0,1))$ is separable, since bounded and limit at 0 and 1 exist (BV prevents oscillating between 2 values)...